# How to delete an input based on id and value in Html agility pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Given below is the html parsed by agility pack

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="1">
                <p>Name*</p>
                <p>
                    <input type="text" size="24" title="Name" id="Name" name="Name" />
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="1">
                <p>Age*</p>
                <p>
                    <input type="text" size="24" title="Age" id="Age" name="Age" />
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="1">
                <p>Date*</p>
                <p>
                    <input type="text" size="24" title="Date" id="Date" name="Date" />
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="1">&#160;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&#160;<span>&#160;<input type="text" id="txtCaptcha" readonly="readonly" />&#160;
    <input type="button" onclick="RenderCaptcha()" value="Refresh" /><br />&#160;
    <input type="text" style="width: 140px;" id="txtverification" /></span> &#160;
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="1">
                <p id="radETempNode">&#160;
                    <input type="submit" class="brochur" value="Submit" id="ComplaintFormSubmit" /> &#160;
                    <input type="button" class="brochur" value="Reset" id="ComplaintFormReset" /> &#160;
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to remove the inputs with id **ComplaintFormReset,ComplaintFormSubmit,txtverification** and the one with value **Refresh**.

Is there any way to do this?

Given below is the code that i have tried

```
       var document = new HtmlDocument();
        document.LoadHtml(Html);

       var nodes = new Queue<HtmlNode>(document.DocumentNode.Descendants());

        while (nodes.Count > 0)
        {

            var node = nodes.Dequeue();
            //if (node.Name != "strong" && node.Name != "em" && node.Name != "u" && node.Name != "#text")
            if(node.Id!="")
            {
             var parentNode = node.ParentNode;

                if (node.Attributes["id"] != null && (string.Compare(node.Attributes["id"].Value, "txtverification", StringComparison.InvariantCulture) == 0 || string.Compare(node.Attributes["id"].Value, "ComplaintFormSubmit", StringComparison.InvariantCulture) == 0 || string.Compare(node.Attributes["id"].Value, "ComplaintFormReset", StringComparison.InvariantCulture) == 0))
                {
                    if (null != node.ParentNode)
                    {
                        parentNode.RemoveChild(node, true);
                        //nodes.Enqueue(node);
                    }
                    //node.RemoveAll();
                }
            }
        }

        string dd =document.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;// this final htm still contains the node i had tried to remove
```

Is there anything wrong with me?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with you!

It looks like your code will work for the inputs with id **ComplaintFormReset**,**ComplaintFormSubmit**, and **txtverification** but **not** the one with value **Refresh**.

There are two reasons for this

1. You need to remove the `if(node.Id!="")` check, since the input with value **Refresh** has no Id attribute
2. You need to add a check for the node with 'value' attribute equal to "Refresh"

this code will work

```
        var document = new HtmlDocument();
        document.LoadHtml(Html);

        var nodes = new Queue<HtmlNode>(document.DocumentNode.Descendants());

        while (nodes.Count > 0)
        {
            var node = nodes.Dequeue();
                var parentNode = node.ParentNode;

                if (node.Attributes["id"] != null && 
                    (string.Compare(node.Attributes["id"].Value, "txtverification", StringComparison.InvariantCulture) == 0 ||
                     string.Compare(node.Attributes["id"].Value, "ComplaintFormSubmit", StringComparison.InvariantCulture) == 0 ||
                     string.Compare(node.Attributes["id"].Value, "ComplaintFormReset", StringComparison.InvariantCulture) == 0)
                    ||
                    node.Attributes["value"] != null &&
                    string.Compare(node.Attributes["value"].Value, "Refresh",
                        StringComparison.InvariantCulture) == 0)
                {
                    if (null != node.ParentNode)
                    {
                        parentNode.RemoveChild(node, true);
                    }
                }
        }

        string dd = document.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
```